# Perl's File::Find::Rule Amount/Quantity-Rule?

Tags: perl, head, tail, file-find

When I have a folder with about 5000 images and I use the following code:

```
my $path= "./foo/images"
my @files = File::Find::Rule->file()->name('*.jpg')->in($path);
```

I should get 5000 Images in my Array.

But are there equivalents with perl or a shell function like `tail` and `head`, or any other way, to get the last 100 images for example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just realised... File::Find::Rule completly mixes up the images...
so we need a sort additionally before slicing the Array

so finally I/we have to use the following:

for the first 5:

```
my @files = (sort File::Find::Rule->file()->name('*.jpg')->in($path))[0 .. 4];
```

for the last 5:

```
my @files = (reverse sort File::Find::Rule->file()->name('*.jpg')->in($path))[0 .. 4];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an [array slice](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Slices).  This gets the 1st 5 returned:

```
my @files = (File::Find::Rule->file()->name('*.jpg')->in($path))[0 .. 4];
```

This gets the last 5:

```
my @files = (reverse File::Find::Rule->file()->name('*.txt')->in($path))[0 .. 4];
```

Comment: wouldn'T it get the first 6? and... how about the last ones? only possible after a scalar, or?